# How to make a div responsive and use a fixed size?

Tags: html, responsive-design

I have a div within a  tag, this has a fixed width, height and margin.

```html
<center>
  <div id="360container" style="width:1252px; height:805px; margin-right:50px; margin-left:50px">This is div
  </div>
</center>
```

I want to decrease the width when this div not fit's the browser anymore, when the browser width is less than 1252+50+50px, and i want the height to decrease but still keep the same ratio(1252x805).

How can this be done?

Comment: Did anyone mention `max-width: 1252px` and `width: 100%` ?

Answer (score 2):

When you want to apply  a specific style when the screen size width between 320px and 480px for example ,You can use  ( @media queries) to detect the screen size.:

```
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 480px)
   {
/* your style here */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following CSS :

```
 #360container {
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 64.2%; /* 805 is 64.2% of 1252 */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code and let me know whether it satisfies you or not.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en-US">
    <head>
    <style>
    .city {
        float: left;
        margin: 5px;
        padding: 15px;
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <h1>W3Schools Demo</h1>
    <h2>Resize this responsive page!</h2>

    <div class="city">
      <h2>London</h2>
      <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
      <p>It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="city">
      <h2>Paris</h2>
      <p>Paris is the capital and most populous city of France.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="city">
      <h2>Tokyo</h2>
      <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan, the center of the Greater Tokyo Area, and the most populous metropolitan area in the world.</p>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that may work, pure CSS

```
<div id="360container" style="position: relative; height: 0; margin:0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;width:60%; max-width:500px; padding-bottom:25%;  border:1px solid #000;">

        <div style="position:absolute; top:0;width:100%;height:100%;max-height:200px;background:#ccc;"></div>

    </div>
```

Take a look at the fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/je3g4evs/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.aDiv {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 480px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mrz240sa/7/

Answer (score -1):

if you want your website to be responsive use percentage widths instead of pixels....
for eg.

```
<style>
    .city {
        float: left;
        margin: 5px;
        padding: 15px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 300px;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
</style>
    <h1>W3Schools Demo</h1>
    <h2>Resize this responsive page!</h2>

    <div class="city">
      <h2>London</h2>
      <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
      <p>It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.</p>
    </div>
```